# How to Analyze JVM Garbage Collection?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, jvm

I have been tasked with analyzing Garbage Collection.  I’ve configured the server for logging GC and the stats are delivered correctly.  Now that I have GC information I have a question about tuning.  After plugging my GC file into an analyzing tool I see that there are no Full GC only minor GC.  Is this a problem?
Also if you look at the following line...

```
[PSYoungGen: 454784K->14336K(450688K)] 685884K->258421K(1761408K), 8.6630322 secs] [Times: user=30.25 sys=1.20, real=8.66 secs]
```

Does this mean….

```
454784K->14336K = Usage of Young generation before and after collection
```

To me this looks like there were more younger GC before than after collections.  In this case should I create a new ratio?  Or am I looking at this backwards?

```
685884K->258421K = Total used heap before and after collection
```

Furthermore, the highest time I have after running a JMeter test is...

```
[Times: user=30.25 sys=1.20, real=8.66 secs]
```

The lowest time I have is

```
[Times: user=0.73 sys=0.29, real=0.16 secs]
```

Does this mean I need to focus on the code to see why that specific task is so high?  Maybe it’s a threading/DB issue?

Should I be trying to get these numbers as close as possible 454784K->14336K?
Do I need Full GC?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what your objective is.  You GC times will vary based on a number of factors, the most important being

- was a Full GC performed.
- how much of the data was retained from the young generation.

IMHO The best way to improve performance is to reduce your allocation rate.  This will make your code faster between GC pauses, reduce the number of GC pauses, and make your application easier to tune. I suggest trying Flight Recorder to monitor your memory allocations.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  I will look into reducing the allocation rates.  Is it safe to say a Full GC was not performed since I don't see any Full GC in the logs.  Only PSYoungGen.  Or maybe the Full GC takes time to show in the log maybe a day or two?

Comment: @Angular_Newbie A full GC typically occurs when the tenured space fills up.  How long this takes depends on your application and configuration. It could be seconds or days.  You can watch the GC regions with `jstat -gccause {pid} 10s` so you can see each region as it fills and when a GC occurs and why.